# counter increment each code execution without database or external file

Tags: php, bash, logic, counter, increment

i wanna write script to display **incremental counter for each code execution without using some sort of read/write to file or database integration.**

so for the first time execution it will displays "1" , the next run is 1 +1 so it will displays "2" and so on, after n number (you can say, 50) of execution it will return back to 0, so next code execution will displays "1" again.

this is done easily with file_put_contents to put counter externally or using loop (but only for one time execution).

programming code is not specific, but i prefer **php/bash** (i use centos 5).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a request for someone else to write the code, rather than a specific question about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use *some* kind of external storage to store the variable.

If you are using PHP, you can make good use of [apc](http://www.php.net/apc-inc) or [memcache](http://www.php.net/memcached.increment).

Comment: i think there is no apc in my server, maybe i will use memcache, did they storage have expiration date or similar one?

Comment: @ShinDapaty Yes memcache comes with expires if you need, or can be infinite. Data can also be kicked out if memcache runs out of its memory.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] +1;
echo $_SESSION['counter'];
```

it actually does use some behind the scense storage, but you don't have to deal with it yourself.

Comment: thank you , this is done if i use browser, what about using CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        for i in {0..5}; do
                [ "$i" -gt 5 ] && i=0
                sleep 1;
                echo $i
        done
done
```

Can you clarify your question?  Or is this really what you're after?  If the goal is to simply increment a counter, I don't think anyone would first consider writing to disk or using a database.

EDIT: added a sleep so you can see what's happening, which you can remove.  CTRL-C to interrupt by the way

Comment: thanks, but the counter will always start from zero again when i execute this, i want the counter goes increment for each execution